# SQL Query to Find Duplicates (SQL Server Mngt Studio 2008)

Tags: count, duplicates

I have been trying to get a SQL query (in SQL Server Mngt Studio 2008) written to identify duplicates based on a few columns (not the entire record) in a single table but I am getting results that include records that are not duplicates.  What is the best way to write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH CTEDUPLICATESALARY AS
(
    SELECT SALARY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SALARY ORDER BY SALARY)  AS ROWNUMBER FROM EmployeeSalary 
)

SELECT * FROM CTEDUPLICATESALARY
WHERE CTEDUPLICATESALARY.ROWNUMBER>1
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This works great!  I was able to get what I wanted by modifying the SELECT and PARTITION BY to include all of the desired columns.

'WITH DUPLICATE AS
(SELECT ORGNL_ASMT_ID, INTRNL_ID, TRGT_DT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ORGNL_ASMT_ID,INTRNL_ID, TRGT_DT ORDER BY ORGNL_ASMT_ID)  AS ROWNUMBER FROM dbo.ASMT )

SELECT * FROM DUPLICATE
WHERE DUPLICATE.ROWNUMBER>1'